# Tests Failed: 0 passed, 1 failed When use Junit test my method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJil2.jpg)

My code is below:

```
@Test
public void testTrans() {

    AccountDao accountDao = new AccountDao();
    accountDao.trans();
    System.out.printf("test trans()");
}
```

When I using Junit to test the method, occurs the issue, this below is Event Log information:

> 2017/2/15
> 上午10:08   All files are up-to-date
>
> 上午10:08   Tests Failed: 0 passed, 1 failed

**Update**

This is my `AccountDao.java` , and in it

```
public class AccountDao {

private Connection con;
private PreparedStatement pstmt;

 
public void trans() {

    String sql_zs = "UPDATE account SET money=money-100 WHERE accountName='zhangsan';";
    String sql_ls = "UPDATE account SET money=money+100 WHERE accountName='李四';";

    try {
         
        con = JdbcUtil.getConnection();   
        con.setAutoCommit(false);         
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql_zs);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

         
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql_ls);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        try {
            con.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }finally {
        JdbcUtil.closeAll(con, pstmt, null);
        try {
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

And it invoke this method in the end , to change the money, in the navicat the money did not change:

[image]

Comment: So you have one test and it failed. (Your test is useless, BTW. It doesn't test anything and doesn't indicate success if it passes.) What is your question?

Comment: Are you sure you running the correct test suite ? Cos i didn't see the line `printf` on the console

Comment: Downvote for stupid title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maer I think you are missing an assert statement.  Assuming that your .trans function changes a some value inside of your object you can assert that those changes are happening.  I will link you the assert documentation.  http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html  Once you implement one of the assert methods to assert that something is true your test should pass.

Example of using assert:

```
@Test
public void passingTest(){
  Assert.assertEquals(1, 1); // This will pass.
}

@Test
public void failingTest(){
  Assert.assertEquals(1,2); // This will fail.
}
```

Good luck man.  Happy to see you testing your code.

Comment: Hey!  Glad it worked out buddy.  Good luck with testing!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is some exception while executing the test case.You should check the console for any exception.I dont see any assertions in your testcase...what is it that you want to test??

Answer (score -1):

[image]
应该是你的test方法没有放在test包里的问题吧。。。。。。

Comment: try to use english in the place like this please

Comment: @邹远锋  How to do with that?

Comment: I think you can try to break point debugging。I was using gradle get, with your catalog structure is not the same, my test method is not placed in the test package can not be used, I just tried to get the database connection, wrote a query, but also can be normal Did not try your question